# How to display two forms next to each other

Tags: html, css

I am not very strong with css but what I have is 2 forms below:

```
    //below is where it displays course name

        $outputcourse = ""; 
        $outputcourse .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $course .  " - "  . $coursename . "</p>";

    //below is where it displays module name

    $outputmodule = ""; 
    $outputmodule = sprintf("<p><strong>Module:</strong> %s - %s</p>", $moduleId, $moduleName);

    //below is form where it displays assessments drop down menu

        $assessmentform = "<form action='".htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."' method='post'>
<p>{$outputcourse}</p>
<p>{$outputmodule}</p>
        <p><strong>Assessments:</strong> {$sessionHTML} </p>   
        </form>";

        echo $assessmentform;

        }

        //below is form where it displays all of the text inputs and submit button

        $editsession = "<form id='updateForm'>

            <p><strong>Current Assessment's Date/Start Time:</strong></p>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>Assessment:</th>
            <td><input type='text' id='currentAssessment' name='Assessmentcurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Date:</th>
            <td><input type='text' id='currentDate' name='Datecurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Start Time:</th>
            <td><input type='text' id='currentTime' name='Timecurrent' readonly='readonly' value=''/> </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <div id='currentAlert'></div>

            <p><strong>New Assessment's Date/Start Time:</strong></p>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>Assessment:</th>
            <td><input type='text' id='newAssessment' name='Assessmentnew' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Date:</th> 
            <td><input type='text' id='newDate' name='Datenew' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th>Start Time:</th> 
            <td><input type='text' id='newTime' name='Timenew' readonly='readonly' value=''/><span class='timepicker_button_trigger'><img src='Images/clock.gif' alt='Choose Time' /></span> </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <div id='datetimeAlert'></div>

            </form>

            <p><button id='updateSubmit'>Update Date/Start Time</button></p>

            <div id='targetdiv'></div>
        ";

        echo $editsession;
```

CSS:

```
form#assessmentForm {
 float: left; 
 border: 1px solid red;
}
form#updateForm {
 float:left;
 clear: right;
 /* with some space to the left of the second form */
 margin-right: 100px; 
}
p#submitupdatebtn {
  clear: both;
}
```

At the moment both form are displayed above one another. What I really want to do is display `$editsession` form to be displayed next to the `$assessmentform` form on the right hand side with a little space in between the two forms.

How can this be achieved? And I want this to work in all Major browsers.

Below shows two screenshots merged together to show how I want it to be displayed:

[image]

Thanks

UPDATE:

Below is now what it is displaying:

[image]

Comment: dude why would you assign your form to a variable and than echo it.. u know you can write html inside PHP right?

Comment: @Dinesh it is because I don't want the form to appear until the right details have been submitted. If the validation is passed then it displays both forms. The code in my question isn't the whole code, just relevant code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to [`float: left;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float) the forms, and it is recommended to also `clear: right;` the second form, so that other floating elements don't appear to the right of it.  Finally, `clear: both;` on the `<p>` that follows the second form so no preceding element floats to the left or right of it.

```
form {
 /* Float both forms to the left */
 float: left; 
 /* borders added for visibility. Just remove them */
 border: 1px solid red;
}
form#updateForm {
 clear: right;
 /* with some space to the left of the second form */
 margin-right: 20px; 
}
/* Give an id to the <p> which follows the second form and clear: both */
p#submit {
  clear: both;
}
```

In your markup, give the `<p>` which follows the second form an id, so it can be easily targeted in the CSS

```
<p id='submit'><button id='updateSubmit'>Update Date/Start Time</button></p>
```

Then move it *inside* the preceding `<form>` tag, since it is a part of that form.

[Here is a demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/masku/5/)

Comment: This is my fault I realized I don't want lined up next to the other form (the drop down menu), but I want to align it next to the course name. I have included a screen shot where I merged two separate images together from my app to show how I want it displayed. I also updated code to show code which outputs course and module name

Comment: @user1830984 Just move that `<p>` inside the `<form>` tag. I updated the jsfiddle demo link above, and it looks pretty much exactly as your screen shot.

Comment: Hi, I have updated code to include the `<p>` in the form. I am just having 2 problems which you can see in the screenshot under the UPDATE section of the question. The submit button is not displayed under the second form and there is no space between the 2 forms. I can't put the button in the form because then it would not perform the submit correctly. Code updated

Comment: If you can't place it in the form (even though it belongs there), then wrap each side in a `<div>` and float those the same way.  See http://jsfiddle.net/masku/6/

Answer (score 0):

Use the float

you just need to add this to your first form tag,

and then the second one jumps on the right of your first form